# How to use pandas cut value counts for two bins in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to find the value count of two bins after using pandas cut?

Here is my code so far...

```
#creating dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Times': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100], 'Y-Values': [5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9, 3, 5, 4]})

#creating bins for each variable
df['TimeBins'] = pd.cut(x=df['Times'], bins=[0,25,50,75,100])
df['YBins'] = pd.cut(x=df['Y-Values'], bins=[0,2,4,6,8,10])

print(df)
------------

output:
    Times  Y-Values    TimeBins    YBins
0    10      5          (0, 25]    (4, 6]
1    20      6          (0, 25]    (4, 6]
2    30      5          (25, 50]   (4, 6]
...  ...   ...         ...          ...
```

I can do value counts like this

```
timeCounts = df['TimeBins'].value_counts()
print(timeCounts)
--------
(0, 25]   2
(25, 50]  1
(50, 75]  ...
...
```

What I want to know, is how would I find the value count of events in, say (0, 25] and (4, 6]
instead of just one of these at a time? For this example, the output would be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either group them into a tupple using `.apply()` or use pandas `.groupby()` with `.count()`

#### Using `.apply()`

```
df.apply(lambda d: (d['TimeBins'], d['YBins']), axis=1).value_counts()
```

output:

```
((75, 100], (2, 4])    2
((0, 25], (4, 6])      2
((50, 75], (6, 8])     1
((25, 50], (4, 6])     1
((75, 100], (4, 6])    1
((25, 50], (2, 4])     1
((25, 50], (0, 2])     1
((50, 75], (8, 10])    1
dtype: int64
```

#### Using `.groupby()` with `.count()`

```
df.groupby(['TimeBins', 'YBins'])['Times'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

output:

```
TimeBins   YBins  
(0, 25]    (4, 6]     2
(75, 100]  (2, 4]     2
           (4, 6]     1
(25, 50]   (0, 2]     1
           (2, 4]     1
           (4, 6]     1
(50, 75]   (8, 10]    1
           (6, 8]     1
(0, 25]    (0, 2]     0
(50, 75]   (4, 6]     0
(75, 100]  (6, 8]     0
           (0, 2]     0
(50, 75]   (0, 2]     0
           (2, 4]     0
(0, 25]    (2, 4]     0
(25, 50]   (8, 10]    0
           (6, 8]     0
(0, 25]    (8, 10]    0
           (6, 8]     0
(75, 100]  (8, 10]    0
Name: Times, dtype: int64
```